# How to close a asyncio(http) connection in Python 3.7+

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

How do you close a asyncio loop in Python 3.7+ ? (I'm new to asynchronous programming especially py 3.7+)

I know it's closed using this inthe previous versions.

```
loop= asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

But now that we've got the new Python. I've searched several pages to see how the closure of a connection is established in Py 3.7+. but nothing satisfied me.
Could anyone tell me how the closure of a loop is done in the new version?

```
asyncio.run(main)

**now how do we close this connection? or is it done by itself?**
asyncio.close() ?
```

Also, if we are not closing the loop...won't be get 'Runtime Error: Event loop is closed' error?

Comment: Are you asking about closing the event loop or closing an HTTP connection? `asyncio.gather` will handle creating, running, and closing the former. You (or whatever HTTP library you’re using) will be responsible for the latter.

Comment: I was referring the event loop. Thanks for your input!! a qeustion: Is it necessary to close the http connection after the completion of the prog?

Comment: You do not need to close the loop. `run` will close it for you. (There is no connection to the loop, we’re talking about closing the loop itself.)

Comment: So all the other functions like asyncio.as_completed, get event loop all is condensed inside asyncio.run?

Comment: All the `run` does it [create a loop, run your coroutine, and close the loop](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/11d75ec807f05eff1148c049e38b808d11c23b8a/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L39-L52).